# Setting title for UINavigation bar in iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, uinavigationbar, title

I am adding image to navigation bar it works fine but when i want to add title

```
   self.title=@"Activity";
```

it does not show anything

using another way i add title label also but this works fine for one view controller but on second controller i change title but it also shows prevoius title

here is my code

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Nav.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];




[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imageView]; 


   titleLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,2,250,36)];
     titleLabel.text=@"Activity";
titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
titleLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size :18];



//titleLabel boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:titleLabel];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of add Image in `UINavigationBar` , set background Image using bellow code..

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[self navigationController] navigationBar];
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Nav.png"];
[navBar setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

and then set Title like bellow...

```
self.title=@"Activity";
```

**UPDATE**

```
    if ([navBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)])
    {
        [navBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Nav.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }
    else
    {
        UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[navBar viewWithTag:1];//any tag
        if (imageView == nil)
        {
            imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Nav.png"]];
            [navBar insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];
            [imageView release];
        }
    }
    self.title=@"Activity";
```

Answer (score 0):

if going for another way as adding subview to navigation bar then in `viewWillDisAppear` method of view you should set the title hidden and on `viewWillAppear` method set hidden false.i was facing same problem as yours.

so whenever you leaving your current view `viewWillDisAppear` method will called and it will hide the current view's title and as you again in same view then `viewWillAppear` method will display the title again.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply hide default navigation bar. and add following code -

```
NavigationView = [[UIView alloc]init];
NavigationView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0 , 320, 44);

UIImageView *TopBarImg = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
TopBarImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Nav.png"];
[NavigationView addSubview:TopBarImg];

TopBarImg.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;

UILabel *TopTitle = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
TopTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
TopTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
TopTitle.text = @"Activity";
TopTitle.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
TopTitle.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
TopTitle.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size :18];
[TopBarImg addSubview:TopTitle];

UIButton *BackButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
BackButton.Frame = CGRectMake(5, 8, 46, 30);
[BackButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[BackButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_btn_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[BackButton addTarget:self action:@selector(BackClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[TopBarImg addSubview:BackButton];


[self.view addSubview:NavigationView];
```

And add one method for back Button click action as follows -

-(void)BackClicked
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}