# How to size a title label to the full width of the navbar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilabel, navbar

I have a title label in the navbar using the code below. I can't seem to get it to size to the width of the full view. Any idea how I might go about fixing this?

I thought `self.view.bounds.size.width` would size it to the full width of the view.

here's my navbar title label code and there's also a screenshot to visually show the problem.

thanks for the help

```
 UILabel* tlabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 48)];
tlabel.text=self.navigationItem.title;
tlabel.text = @"someText"; 
tlabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"DIN-Bold" size:20];
tlabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
tlabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(219/255.0) green:(52/255.0) blue:(31/255.0) alpha:1] ;
tlabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
tlabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
self.navigationItem.titleView=tlabel;
```

[image]

after code change from Paras Joshi it's correct on the right side but off on the left.

[image]

Comment: try with hardcoded width for label, as per screen size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this bellow code in which I've added `UILabel` in `UIView` and then set that view as a titleView...

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 48)];
UILabel* tlabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 48)];
tlabel.text=self.navigationItem.title;
tlabel.text = @"someText"; 
tlabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"DIN-Bold" size:20];
tlabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
tlabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(219/255.0) green:(52/255.0) blue:(31/255.0) alpha:1] ;
tlabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;   
[headerView addSubview:tlabel];
self.navigationItem.titleView = headerView;
```

or add as a subview like below.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:tlabel];
```

Comment: I do have some text in the @""; I just removed it for this post. I need that text there though

Comment: @hanumanDev also try my updated code instead of your code.. :)

Comment: thanks! it's almost perfect. The right side is flush to the end of the view with your code. the left side however is still a few pixels off like in the screenshot.

Comment: ok then take frame of that view or lable with width 324 try it out

Comment: I tried the 324 in the header view width and then also in the label but it's still off. I added a screenshot to illustrate. thanks for all the help :)

Comment: @hanumanDev check out my another answer from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341575/setting-title-for-uinavigation-bar-in-iphone/17341896#17341896 also then try to add as a subview instead of set as a titleview like this `[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:label];`

Comment: solved it with [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:label]; thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it with:

```
UILabel* tlabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, [UIScreen mainscreen].bounds.size.width, 48)];
```

May be it works.

Comment: What about font size of text with respective height and width of Label?

Comment: you want to increase height of the title label as per your title content size?

Comment: @PradhyumanChavda thanks! I get no known class method for selector 'mainScreen' when I try that.

Answer (score 0):

you have imported uikit framework or not.import it to make it error free