# How to apply a background image to navigation bar

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to insert an image to the navigation bar.

My code is

```
 UINavigationBar *navBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bodyBg.png"];
[navBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I have attached the screenshot of the current output. Is this because of the large image size?

[image]

But my desired output is
[image]

Comment: Well yes .... You should reduce the size

Comment: No it should not be the reason for this.

Comment: I am sure it's bcoz of image height. You should really reduce the size. Or else as others said you need to use that image as pattern image.

Comment: Check this link you can get your answer here [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764309/changing-the-uinavigationbar-background-image

Comment: Can you upload your navigation bar image on [imgur](http://imgur.com) so we can see what might be a problem.

Also I described you in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057493/how-to-apply-a-background-image-to-navigation-bar/18057826#18057826) what is the easiest way to implement image to UINavigationBar.

Answer (score 1):

First, make your navigation bar image size 1024x44 pixels nad for retina display 2048x88 pixels.

If you have the same image for UINavigationBar on every view controller, put this to AppDelegate in method **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**:

```
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-background.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
// This will remove shadow in iOS6
        if ([[UINavigationBar class] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(shadowImage)]) {
            [[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[[UIImage alloc] init] autorelease]];
        }
```

And also I see you need custom back button, also put this in AppDelegate:

```
    UIImage *backButtonNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-back.png"];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButtonNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: In that second image, there are those bar button items right.. how to set those buttons in desired position?

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I hope , it will work for u

Answer (score 0):

Use `UINavigationBar's` `setBackgroundImage: forBarMetrics:` method :

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:yourImageHere forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

your `UIImage` should be of `appropriate height and width`. For example iphone 4 retina size would be 640*88 for portrait.

**EDIT** : Point here is if `UIImage` `height` is `bigger` say 150 pixel height it will display that much height and our `UINavigationBar` `height` is `44 pixel`.

Comment: What is new in your answer ? He has also used this method.

Comment: in that second image, there are those bar button items right.. how to set those buttons in desired position?

Answer (score 0):

you can set the color of navigation bar same as your image use below code and you can put image name  which you want to show in navigation bar

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bodyBg.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

try it out with this code..

```
if ([navBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)])
{
    [navBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Nav.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
else
{
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[navBar viewWithTag:1];//any tag
    if (imageView == nil)
    {
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"Nav.png"]];
        [navBar insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];
        [imageView release];
    }
}
```

see my full answer from this link [setting-title-for-uinavigation-bar-in-iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341575/setting-title-for-uinavigation-bar-in-iphone/17341896#17341896)

Comment: in that second image, there are those bar button items right.. how to set those buttons in desired position?

Answer (score 0):

check this link for add background image in `navigationbar` and first you your `navigationbar` 
image size set as `navigationbar`.

[check this  link  here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692487/how-to-add-background-image-on-iphone-navigation-bar)

i hope this code useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
[myNavbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"UINavigationBarBackground.png"] 
           forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

and also this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764309/changing-the-uinavigationbar-background-image)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it works for me:

```
UIView* navigationBGView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
UIImage * targetImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Header_top.png"];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(navigationBGView.frame.size, NO, 0.f);
[targetImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, navigationBGView.frame.size.width, navigationBGView.frame.size.height)];
UIImage * resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
navigationBGView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:resultImage];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:navigationBGView];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```